# Powershell Start-Process fails to start when -Credential argument is added

Tags: command-line, python, powershell, windows-server-2012

If I run this in powershell,

```
Start-Process "c:\Python27\python.exe" -WorkingDirectory "c:\wd" 
-ArgumentList "-m SimpleHTTPServer"
```

It can start the python process as expected

However when I add '-Credential' argument, I can see a powershell credential prompt. After I enter the password, a DOS windows appears very briefly and then disappears. I do not have a chance catch  any error message, if there is one. Here is the command in final form:

```
Start-Process "c:\Python27\python.exe" -WorkingDirectory "c:\wd" 
-ArgumentList "-m SimpleHTTPServer" -Credential "dop001"
```

and the password prompt

[image]

If I use `runas /user:xxx` I can verify that "c:\Python27\python.exe -m SimpleHTTPServer" can run under that user a/c with no issue.

So my questions are:

1) Why `-Credential` causes it to fail?

2) How can I debug it?

Comment: Assume that in addition to the `-Credential` argument you included a variable with the credentials you wanted the process to be used?

Comment: @Zoredache Just `-Credential "dop001"`. I have added more info to my question